# IE7 form put on sigle column instead of double column

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer

OK, i have no idea how it append, this form : http://xquives.kiaistudio.com/new-form/index.php have a two column field. But in IE7 it's in one column, but not in ie8 or 9 or FF of chrome. Can you please tell me what BAD i have done, or how to make IE behave like normal browser. I have take more that 2 hours testing... and i have NO IDEA where to look !

Comment: Doing the "trick" to put <li> item in two column work fine, and is most browser show up well, why not in IE7 ?, this add flexibility to the layout if for a reason i change my mind and what to put it in a one column, i can !

Comment: And BTW,I validate 100% html, so it's should be a "good" start to build compatible html file to show in ALL browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're markup doesn't lend itself well to crappy ie7.  You're markup looks generally like this:

```
<ul>
<li style="float:left width:50%">stuff</li>
<li style="float:left width:50%">stuff</li>
<li style="float:left width:50%">stuff</li>
<li style="float:left width:50%">stuff</li>
<li style="float:left width:50%">stuff</li>
</ul>
```

This is pretty error prone.

You'd be better off with parent containers that drive the columns like so:

```
<div style="width: 50%; float: left">
    <ul>
    <li class="left-column-lis">stuff</li>
    <li class="left-column-lis">stuff</li>
    <li class="left-column-lis">stuff</li>    
    <li class="left-column-lis">stuff</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="width: 50%; float: left">
    <ul>
    <li class="right-column-lis">stuff</li>
    <li class="right-column-lis">stuff</li>
    <li class="right-column-lis">stuff</li>    
    <li class="right-column-lis">stuff</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT: if you're married to this markup structure, you can hack ie7 by adding:

```
UL{*overflow:visible;}
.autocolumn LI {*width: 48%;}
```

The better thing to do is layout your columns in a way like i've described above

Comment: I totally validate html 100%... and this way, i can change my mind from one column to 2 !

Comment: Yep i love, clean and efficien code, that dont play well with IE7, i will check your star css code just to see if it work !